# Как посчитать процентное соотношение значений?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан массив текстовое значение - количество:

```
[('21', 1), ('25', 1), ('28', 1), ('31', 1), ('Данных нет', 14)]
```

Нужно посчитать каков процент каждого значения в общем. Результат должен быть такой:

```
['21', '1 / (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 14)'; '25', '1 / (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 14)'; '28', '1 / (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 14)'; '31', '1 / (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 14)'; 'Данных нет', '14 / (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 14)']
```

где `1/18 - это расчет процентов`.

Есть вот такое представление на SQL:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `user`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `users_by_age` AS
    SELECT 
        `list_of_users`.`age` AS `age`, COUNT(0) AS `number`
    FROM
        `list_of_users`
    GROUP BY `list_of_users`.`age`
```

Можно добавить еще 1 столбик, но как - вопрос.

Comment: Окей, а что у вас не получается сделать, опишете в чем проблема?

Comment: да я даже в общем логику кода не могу придумать, была идея как-то через цикл...

Comment: Уточните, решений вам нужно найти на Питоне или на SQL ?

Comment: Большого значения это не имеет, данные в конечном итоге все-равно будут добавлены в таблицу excell

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov, что это за структура в результате? Если список, то что значит точка с запятой?

Answer (score 0):

1. Посчитать общую сумму членов (18).
2. Для каждой группы, поделить сумму входящих в нее членов на общую сумм - вот ваш процент.

---

На SQL это будет прмерно так же. Считайте сумму в переменной первым запросом, а вторым - выводите по группам деленым на найденную сумму.

Comment: Я понимаю, как рассчитывается процент, вопрос, как это в питоне написать

Comment: Вы сказали - "я даже в общем логику кода не могу придумать". Я вам в общем ответил. Уточняйте вопрос )

Comment: Я даже в общем не могу понять логику кодинга

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить первый пункт - посчитайте сумму всех членов. В Питоне вы вероятно это будете делать циклом от первого до последнего элемента. В SQL это делается оператором COUNT(). Погуглите про тот и другой варианты.

Comment: Это я посчитаю. А вот что дальше делать - хороший вопрос

Comment: @Kromster, какая практическая польза данного ответа? <сарказм>Может стоит еще объяснить как суммировать элементы?</сарказм> ;)

Comment: @MaxU Это мы с вами тут такие умные, знаем про декомпозицию задач и алгоритмику. А у человека об этом, может быть, нет никакого понятия. Считаю что для него такой ответ куда полезнее, чем "вот тебе волшебный кусок кода, вставь сюда и не трожь". Кстати зря сарказм, "Как просуммировать элементы массива" вполне себе годный вопрос.

Comment: @Kromster, мы как бы ведем обсуждение на сайте посвященному практическим вопросам связанным с программированием... Если мы начнем объяснять в ответах алгоритм расчета простого процента - мы далеко зайдём...

Comment: @MaxU не вижу в этом ничего плохого (если это не дубликат).

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все просто:

```
for a in age:
    res_a = round((int(a[1])/count * 100),2)
    print(res_a)
```

Comment: Вы забыли уточнить, как и откуда берется `count`.